# How to grab only one HTML content from same classes using XPATH in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, xpath, rss

I would like to grab a content of a HTML-string that comes from a SimpleXML by using PHP.

So I have a XML-file where I already get the HTML-string from a description tag. This HTML-string has some divs that I don't need. I only would like to fetch a explict content from a path that I do know.

I was reading through different similiar questions but couldn't find a proper solution using XPATH and tried different methods without the wanted success.

So the whole HTML-string is the following:

```
<div class="field field-name-field-image field-type-image field-label-hidden">
    <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item even">
            <a href="/content/menschen"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="field field-name-body field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden">
    <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item even">
            <p>**GRAB JUST THIS TEXT**</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="field field-name-field-tags field-type-taxonomy-term-reference field-label-above">
    <div class="field-label">Tags:&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item even">
            <a href="/tags/louise">Louise</a>
        </div>
        <div class="field-item odd">
            <a href="/tags/gray">Gray</a>
        </div>
        <div class="field-item even">
            <a href="/taxonomy/term/3016">Buch</a>
        </div>
        <div class="field-item odd">
            <a href="/tags/rezension">Rezension</a>
        </div>
        <div class="field-item even">
            <a href="/tags/richtig">Richtig</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So how would you solve this issue when there are same classes with same names?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you can use:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

print $xpath->query('//div[contains(@class,"field-item even")]/p')[0]->textContent;
# **GRAB JUST THIS TEXT**
```

---

[PHP DEMO](https://eval.in/781769)

Comment: Thanks alot. That's it.